# Does the type of deploy affect the application in any way?

Tags: deployment, jboss, filesystems, jmx

My team and I are trying to automatize some of our proccesses and it includes programmatically remote deployment. A colleague of mine asked me a question about JBoss' deployment:

> Does the type of deploy in JBoss, be it JMX or filesystem (copy the app package to the deploy folder), affect the application in any way?

I know that JMX deployment is temporary and filesystem is not. Other than this, there is any difference? I did my research, but I didn't found anything useful or that I could understand (I'm a beginner-to-intermediate Java programmer), only how-to's about different ways to deploy an application.

Peharps someone could shed some light on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using both kind of deployments in my applications and mean of deployment doesn't affect the app in any way. Maybe just only that JMX has to BE enabled (but this default). You could also find [JBoss maven plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/) useful (it can handle deployment, redeployment and so on).

Comment: Thanks, I needed someone to confirm my suspicions. Since I didn't found any evidence of the contrary, I believed there was no difference at all in terms of how the application behaves, but what do/how could I know? 8D

Comment: Maybe someone is going to make a hard proof here but based on my experience it shouldn't make any difference. You also have more protocols then JMX (like Servlet 3) and choosing any of them doesn't make any diffrence in application behavior.